# Updating JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have little confusion. I am trying to update JTable, but the updates are not coming up. This is my present code:

```
private void addTable(){

        table = new JTable();// the table for 'Benchmark' tab
        table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
        table.setBorder(null);  

        data = new Object[][] {
                {"Key", ""},//result[0]
                {"Precision", ""},//result[2]+" %"
                {"Cipher", ""},//result[4]
                {"Language", ""},
                {"Performance", ""},//result[3]
        };


        String [] header = new String[] {"Subject of Interest", "Output"};
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, header);        

        table.setModel(model);


        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(136);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(550);
        GroupLayout gl_panelBenchmark = new GroupLayout(panelBenchmark);
        gl_panelBenchmark.setHorizontalGroup(
                gl_panelBenchmark.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(textInfoCrypto, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 759, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(gl_panelBenchmark.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(10)
                        .addComponent(textPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 739, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGap(10))
                        .addGroup(Alignment.LEADING, gl_panelBenchmark.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(table, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 739, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addContainerGap())
                );
        gl_panelBenchmark.setVerticalGroup(
                gl_panelBenchmark.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panelBenchmark.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(textInfoCrypto)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(textPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(table, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                );
        panelBenchmark.setLayout(gl_panelBenchmark);

    }
```

And this is how I am trying to update, at this stage, a single row. The below code has been invoked from another method:

```
data[0][0]= result[0];
model.fireTableCellUpdated(0, 0);
```

At this stage I can see only the table frames including row names, but no data. Any help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is only local data not contained in the table model. You need to use:

[tableModel.setValue(result[0], 0, 0);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 2):

1. all `fireXxxXxx` event has `DefaultTableModel` implemented and correctly
2. JTable in this from and based on `DefaultTableModel` haven't any issue with update ModelToView or ViewToModel, there no restriction,
3. have to edit your questin with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)
4. before that read [JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
5. especially [JTable and TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Comment: I would love to read it, honestly, but that was pretty urgent. I got no time to learn from the scratch all the issues I encounter.